# How to detect the error for the list of tuples

Tags: python

```
l1 = [[(1,1), (1,2), (1,3)]]

for e in l1:
  for i, c in enumerate(e):
     n = re.search(r'(\d,\d)', c)
     if n:
        num = [int(y) for y in c.split(',')]
        print "num is ", num

        e[i] = Sequence_element(num[0], num[1])

if sorted(l1) != l1:
    raise ValueError, 'l1 is not in sequence' 


class Sequence_element(object):

   def __init__(self, first_elem, second_elem):
       self._first_elem = first_elem
       self._second_elem = second_elem


   def first_elem(self):
       return self._first_elem

   def second_elem(self):
      return self._second_elem
```

This code is to ensure that (1,2) comes after (1,1) and (1,3) comes after (1,1) and (1,2)

The error which I  sorted(l1) gives [(1,3), (1,2), (1,1)]
which is wrong because this should give [(1,1), (1,2), (1,3)] that means the error should not be  raised whereas the error is raised.

Each element of l1 is formed by help of another class which may be the reason that this sorted function doesn't work. What is the possible solution?

Comment: Can't reproduce- this doesn't raise an error for me. What do you mean "Each element of l1 is formed by help of another class"? Does the code above raise the exception for you or is it some other code that has the problem?

Comment: You should probably post the relevant code. The question doesn't seem to make a lot of sense as it is now; the sorting works as you describe it should and `l1 == sorted(l1)`.

Comment: This can't be what you're running; you're trying to do an `re.search` on a non-string, which would give a `TypeError`.

Comment: Did you even try running this? I can see 2 errors, tuple in re.search and split. NVM it seems you edited it. You need to fix the regex now.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting sorted(l1) output as [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)] , and sorted(l1) is equal to l1. I am not getting any error.